# Структура проекта .Net (Java) - классы и интерфейсы

Tags: классы, .net, java

Добрый день.
Давно уже задаюсь вопросом как принято хранить абстракции (интерфейсы, абстрактные классы) и их реализации относительно друг друга? В одной физической папке или в разных? В одном namespace или в разных? Вот возможные варианты (Objects, Base - папки; IObject - интерфейс; ConcreteObjectA и ConcreteObjectB - реализации интерфейса IObject).

**Вариант 1** - все в одной папке и одном namespace:

```
  -> **Objects**
    -> IObject
    -> ConcreteObjectA
    -> ConcreteObjectB
```

**Вариант 2** - папка Base (или подобная) для абстракций:

```
-> **Objects**
  -> **Base**
    -> IObject
  -> ConcreteObjectA
  -> ConcreteObjectB
```

**Вариант 3** - папка Implementration (или подобная) для реализаций:

```
 -> **Objects**
   -> **Implementration**
     -> ConcreteObjectA
     -> ConcreteObjectB
   -> IObject
```

**Вариант 4** - свой (напишу в ответе).

Какой вариант используете вы? Почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется удобным следующий вариант:

- Структура папок эквивалентна неймспейсам. То есть, если неймспейс некоторого класса выглядит как `ProjectName.Dynamic.Stubs`, то этот файл **обязан** располагаться в папке `ProjectName\Dynamic\Stubs`.
- Интерфейсы и реализации не разносятся по отдельным неймспейсам, пока их количество в отдельно взятом неймспейсе кажется разумным.
- В том случае, если количество интерфейсов в отдельно взятом неймспейсе начинает превышать `9-12` штук, то их можно вынести в отдельный вложенный неймспейс `Interfaces.` Реализации же, соответственно, выносятся в неймспейс `Implementation` или `Impl`.

> - Реальный пример, в котором произведено выделение отдельных неймспейсов для интерфейсов и их реализаций — `Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces` и `Rhino.Mocks.Impl`.
> - Реальный пример, в котором такое отделение не произведено (что, кстати, *не повредило читаемости*) — `System.Linq,` в котором есть и интерфейсы типа `IQueryProvider` и их конкретные реализации типа `EnumerableQuery<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

Это зависит от плана использования. Скажем у вас интерфейсик, который (вы уверены в этом) будет использоваться только в пределах вашего проекта, тогда ему самое место рядом с реализацией.

А если ваш интерфейс/абстрактный класс планируется использовать и в других проектах, то лучше это вынести в отдельный неймспейс/пакет/каталог.

Логика здесь в следующем: если далее планируется reusability кода, то потенциальному потребителю наверное не очень интересна ваша реализация/имплементация абстракций, соответственно он(а) возьмет/импортирует только сами абстракции.

**Пример:** пакет [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html), который содержит в себе декларации абстракций для работы через JDBC, а их конкретная реализация всегда содержится отдельно и обычно предоставляется вендором JDBC драйвера. Например для Oracle это пакет `oracle.jdbc` [выглядит так](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/package-summary.html)